# error Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php

```
$query = "Insert Into dbo_dailyline (Entry_date, Work_Center, Shift_Length, Number_Sewers, Deduct_Hours, Garment_Type, Other, Quantity, Notes)
values ('" .$Entry_Date. "', '" . $Shift_Length . "', '" .$Coats . "', '" . $Number_Sewers . "', '" . $Deduct_Hours . "', '" . $Garment_Type . "' , '" . $Garment_Type . "', '" . $Other . "', '" . $Quantity . "', '" . $Notes . "')";
```

error Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: Can you form this into a question please? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two time `$Garment_Type` remove one

```
$query = "Insert Into dbo_dailyline (
        Entry_date
        , Work_Center
        , Shift_Length
        , Number_Sewers
        , Deduct_Hours
        , Garment_Type
        , Other
        , Quantity
        , Notes)
          values ('" . 
            $Entry_Date. "', '" . 
            $Shift_Length . "', '" .
            $Coats . "', '" . 
            $Number_Sewers . "', '" . 
            $Deduct_Hours . "', '" . 
            $Garment_Type . "' , '" . 
            $Other . "', '" . 
            $Quantity . "', '" . 
            $Notes . "')";
```

Comment: thank i appreciate there is a way to restart the id column to 0

Comment: if the id is an autoincrement column  .. you should drop and (re)create the table  .. otherwise you should update the values ..